# Setup local LDAP server in mac OSX

Tags: macos, openldap

I've followed this (https://github.com/IntersectAustralia/acdata/wiki/Setting-up-OpenLDAP) tutorial for set up LDAP server in my local machine.

I've done all these steps

1. Installed Homebrew
2. Installed openldap using brew command, including berkeley db
3. Updated the slapd.conf file
4. Started the server using command "sudo /usr/local/libexec/slapd"

Now how do i know the LDAP server is running?

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about programming.  Try http://apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: From the page you linked to - "Using rake db:populate will build a up the necessary directory structure in your local LDAP instance for development.

Then you can do a test query:

ldapsearch -D 'cn=admin,dc=localhost' -W -x -b 'o=unsw,dc=localhost'"

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. When i do rake db:populate in jn terminal i get this error "No rake file found". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If anyone is still looking for this, following seems to work for me.
[Setting up OpenLDAP under MAC OS X](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/05/setting-up-openldap-under-mac-os-x.html)

Comment: I have changed the README instructions of OpenLDAP to a [working instruction guide](https://github.com/IntersectAustralia/acdata/wiki/Setting-up-OpenLDAP). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 15):

I tried a lot but i could'nt succeed,later i deiced to go with ADS (http://directory.apache.org/studio/). Its easy to set up. Believe me i made the installation and configuration in 5 mins. Thank you apache.

Answer (score 6):

Use `-d3` suffix.

Run `sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -d3`, it will show you the details.

Comment: Yes, it shows this. :-)  sudo: /usr/local/libexec/slapd: command not found