# openLDAP installation on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, openldap

I too followed the github link mentioned in the question [ [Setup local LDAP server in mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214955/setup-local-ldap-server-in-mac-osx) ] and have same questions as of that question. I installed openldap on mac OS as per the github guidelines but could'nt find any DB_CONFIG.example file anywhere. 
I dont understand where I went wrong also as I did not get any errors while running the server command [ sudo /usr/libexec/slapd ]

So How do I know if my server has started?

PS: I have same questions as above reffered stack overflow question but I'm not yet permitted to comment/ re ask there. 
Also this is my first question in stack overflow so not sure if I missed any details. 
Attaching my screenshot of installation of Openldap and Berkeley db. I have set the paths and flags as suggested.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running `/usr/libexec/slapd -d3` this should tell you if openldap is running or if openldap ran into an error during startup.